# Tunnel a local webserver to AWS Openvpn server and serve traffic from AWS IP address?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, web-server, openvpn

I am running a LEMP server locally behind my router. Everything is working as it should. Because I would prefer that my ip address isn't exposed to the world, I am attempting to tunnel the web server through an AWS Instance running Ubuntu 18.04. I "thought", that It would be as easy as building the AWS Ubuntu OpenVPN cloud server, connecting my local webserver to that server via openvpn in the terminal, and then changing my dns A records to point towards the Amazon VPN server's IP address.

Apparantly, there is something I am missing, as I have done all of the above assumptions, yet, I still cannot get my webserver to serve traffic on my AWS IP address.

My setup:
My Local web server is successfully connected to my ubuntu aws instance via openvpn.
My local web server is recieving my aws instance's IP address properly.
The Openvpn server seems to be working properly.
My DNS configuration has it's A records pointing towards my AWS instance's ip address.
I can browser the internet via the tunnel and whatsmyip.org is showing the proper aws ip address.

On the EC2 instance, the output of `ip addr show` is

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:86:bb:81:3b:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.47.112/20 brd 172.31.47.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 3208sec preferred_lft 3208sec
    inet6 fe80::c86:bbff:fe81:3bdd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2405:76a5:410a:17a7/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On the local webserver the output of `ip addr show` is

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:14:6d:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.30.32/24 brd 192.168.30.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::815e:ba7:5be8:1fb5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:14:6d:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.3/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::292b:b09f:9ac9:2cc7/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On my EC2 Instance, the output of `sudo iptables -t nat -vnL` is:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 396 packets, 22897 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 173 packets, 8430 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 361 packets, 44271 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 361 packets, 44271 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  223 14467 SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.8.0.0/24         !10.8.0.0/24          to:172.31.47.112
```

On my local server the output of `sudo iptables -t nat -vnL` is:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

As Far as I can tell, my Ip address is not changing upon reboot or restart of the vpn server. Lastly, in oder to set up the vpn server on the EC2 side, is followed the following guide incase you want to check it out:

https://linuxhint.com/vpn_amazon_ec2_setup/

Aftere this setup, my webserver, is not serving traffic on the amazon ip address.

Could anyone tell me what exactly I might be missing here and how to remedy it?

Comment: So you already have a server in aws. Why don't you run your web stack from there and instead try to play some VPN trickery??

Comment: Because I am using AWS Free tier server. I am trying spend zero dollars, which is possible when running a raspberry pi server locally, but not when I would have to pay for more space on an aws instance if i wanted to run it directly from there. The second reason, is to learn. I learn best from real hardware as opposed to cloud computing, so I'd rather start with the basics using real hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the need to port forward /dnat the traffic on the AWS instance back across your VPN (and maybe binding to the web server on the tunnel IP and/or local firewalling - but dnat us the big one).

You havnt provided your addressing, but you most likely have a NAT masquerade rule on your AWS iptables/firewall instance to allow browsing from your VPN. You also need to ensure AWS allows inbound connections for http(s). You need to add a rule like (untested)

**updated**

```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0  -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.3:80
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0  -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.3:443
```

You will need to ensure these rues are added to your AWS server on reboot. The first is for http, the second for https.

If you imagine your AWS box as a virtual SOHO router - the router/AWS box is, by default, configured to allow outbound connection, but does not know where to redirect incoming ones.  The above lines are equivalent to setting up port forwards in the router to redirect traffic coming in on the routers external address to the internal  IP of the server.

We know the IP address of the web server is 10.8.0.3 because of the 4th entry of the "ip address show " output which is for the run interface, which is the openvpn tunnel.

Comment: How can I provide addressing for you to look at? I am very much a noob still. Below are my iptables:                                                                                                                     
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source destination
ACCEPT udp  --  anywhere  anywhere udp dpt:openvpn
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target  prot opt source  destination
ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere  anywhere state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT  all  --  ip-10-8-0-0.ec2.internal/24  anywhere
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source     destination

Comment: I am very much a noob still. Might you be able to walk me through the next few steps?

Comment: I do have my AWS set up to allow incoming connections via http and https as well. I'm just very confused when it comes to iptables. It scares me.

Comment: How would I go about finding the endpoint on my webserver to verify that it is indeed 10.0.0.2.10:80 ?

Comment: Its likely not 10.0.0.2 - I used that as an example. Can you edit your question to include the output if "IP addr show". (Put a comment below to " pung"/me so U can look at it.

Comment: Also, how did you get thus VPN setup? Its important as its possible that this address changes whenever the VPN restarts - depending on the configuration. (Although it probably doesn't)

Comment: With respect of iptables, there is additional stuff - you may want to provide the output of "iptables -t nat -vnL" to show the contents if the NAT table

Comment: Pinging you because I updated my question to include the requested information! THank you so much sir!

Comment: I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: When entering the iptables command I get the following error: iptables v1.6.1: Cannot use -I with -A

Comment: Sorry, try a small I (-I is for INSERT rule. I think -i is interface. Android autocorrect sucks.)

Comment: Okay great! We have made progress! Your command worked and now I am able to see the webserver. The last two things I need, are now, it seems my ip address when logging into the vpn server changes. After reboot it is now 10.8.0.2. Two things. 1) Is there a way to make this a static ip so it always uses the same ip on the vpn? 2) Is there a way to make openvpn startup autmatically after reboot or anytime that it is down? I tried using sudo crontab @reboot command but it didn't work. Any other hints? Or should this be left to a new question?

Comment: They are different questions, and really more suitable on superuser.com then here.  With respect of a static IP address for your OpenVPN it depends on your config - which you should post alongside a new question (with private key removed ofcourse) if required.

Comment: I am aware of at least 2 ways of persisting an OpenVPN IP - Use an option like "ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt" will create a list of accounts and their associated IPs.   Alternatively, specify the IPs in a file for each client.  You want to add the directive like  ifconfig-push 10.0.8.249 10.0.8.250  to an appriately named file in the directory named in the directive client-config-dir.. The file should have the same name as the clientname specified in pkitool (I guess this assumes you are using easyrsa) or the CN name in the subject for the crt.

Comment: @RanDan Making openvpn startup automatically on boot or at other times depends entirely on your distro.   Normally you can create a file /etc.rc.local and make it world executable and it will run on startup.    Your distro likely has some syntax to start OpenVPN on startup, but how depends on if its systemd or something else.   A cronjob should work provided cron is running - there may be network dependencies which need to come up first?

Comment: I was able to start openvpn client at boot by renaming the .opvn file to a .conf file and placing it in the /etc/openvpn directory. Now Rasbpian starts the openvpn client successfully at boot and logs in properly to the vpn server. On to the next! I will report back soon!

Comment: Ok I am re-reading your post about "2 ways of persisting an OpenVPN IP" and I'm just not putting it together or grasping it. Would the ifconfig-pool-persist.txt be created on the server or client? And in what directory? What must I do after it creates a list of accounts and ip's?

Comment: sorry for such late responses. I got swamped with work!

Comment: Ifconfig-pool-persist /path/to/persist.file directive exists in the server cinfig, and provided its on disk (ie non volatile memory) it will automatically record the IPs it gives out alongside the name of the client. It will use this list to try assign the same IP for that client in future. If the directive is there it should be automatic.

Comment: Ahh yes! Now i understand. Turns out I do have ifconfig-pool-persist /path directive in my server.conf file and the file it references exists and has the correct client name and ip address in it. I think this is working now! Thank you so much!